# how to migrate git to gitlab migration with history (existing branches and tags)

Tags: gitlab-omnibus

I setup the new fresh GitLab server and i want to migrate my git repositories to gitlab server. I am following below steps but i am getting the error.

```
git clone --mirror Git repo URL  
git remote add NEW-REMOTE Git Lab repo URL  
git push  NEW-REMOTE --mirror
```

finally it through an **error**

> remote: fatal: Error in object
>
> error: pack-objects died of signal 13

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe gitlab has it's own git import tool built into the interface. When creating a new project you can import an existing git repo with it. Any history and branches will be included.

screenshot:

[image]